# SQL Server 2008 Stored Procedure Select column from last row in table using ORDER BY column DESC

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

New to stored procedures. I have a table with the following two columns

```
ID (identity)
NoPro = CCNNN  where CC = Country Code and NNN sequential number within country
```

Data:

```
1   AR101
2   AR102
3   AR103
4   BO101
5   BO102
6   BR101
7   BR102
```

In the stored procedure I want to access the last project for a specific country in order to assign the next project number for that country.

I was trying the following code:

```
select @sNo = [NoPro] 
from projects 
where substring([NoPro], 1, 2) = @Country 
order by NoPro DESC
```

If I use `AR` for country I get `AR101` while I was expecting `AR103`.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Please publish the full source code for generating the new values for `NoPro`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the max `NoPro` value for your country should fix your issue and if you change the where clause to use `like` you might even use a index on `NoPro` to find the row you are looking for.

The design you have here is a bit troublesome when it comes to concurrency so please do at least create a unique constraint on `NoPro` to prevent duplicates.

```
select @sNo = max(NoPro)
from projects 
where NoPro like @Country+'%';
```

Comment: I guess I made it more complicated then it needed to be :D

Comment: Yep, looks like it. It also looks like you are using a column alias in the where clause in your second solution.

Comment: Nope you are not, I'm on a phone here and can't see straight.

Comment: I have just compared both of solution and embarrassingly mine was 82% and yours was 18% of the batch :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this is to use `top`:

```
select top 1 @sNo = [NoPro] 
from projects 
where substring([NoPro], 1, 2) = @Country 
order by NoPro DESC;
```

Your query is returning multiple rows.  Which gets assigned to `@sNo` is either arbitrary or the last value processed -- I'm not sure if SQL Server guarantees this.  In any case, the solution is to fix the query to return one value.

Comment: this solution is almost 4 times more expensive then what Mikael has suggested.

Comment: @M.Ali . . . Interesting.  I suggested this because it is most similar to the OP's original query.  I didn't realize the performance would be *that* much worse.

Comment: @M.Ali - The estimated costs shown there should be taken with a heavy dose of salt. A `TOP N` sort where `N =1` and a stream aggregate calculating the `MAX` basically do exactly the same thing (remember the largest value they have seen). The TOP N Sort doesn't actually sort the whole input unless N > 100 but it gets costed as though it does. See [Sorting, Row Goals, and the TOP 100 Problem](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/27/sorting-row-goals-and-the-top-100-problem.aspx) for more about that operator.

Comment: Thank you @MartinSmith for the useful links. With my minimal knowledge of execution plans and performance optimization, I normally write a query in couple of different ways and compare the estimated costs of them queries and then pick the cheapest one. I though it was a good way to optimize my code :S